# Rails - Adding html tag to a image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image_tag in rails. I have a jquery plugin that requires me to add a tag `data-elem=pinchzoomer` to enable touch zoom. How do I add this to the below?

`image_tag(@listing.image.url, class: "rsTmb img-responsive")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
image_tag(@listing.image.url, class: "rsTmb img-responsive", data: {elem: 'pinchzoomer')
```

For data elements, just add the key 'data' to the hash you're passing to the helper method, and use the bit after "data-" to be the keys to the hash. So, if you wanted to have data-foo='fred' data-bar='barney', you'd add:

```
data: {foo: 'fred', bar: 'barney'}
```